# Keeping Seekbar values when replacing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-inflate

I'm having a navigation drawer with 4 items (Home,settings,about,help). On a click on the item, the fragment corresponding to the item replace the other one.

Now, I have this settings fragment with 3 seekbar, if a user change the value of the seekbar and after he open the navigation drawer and click home and come back to setting fragment the seekbar is back to 0"

How do I keep the seekBar at the same state before changing fragment.

This is the code when the view is create in the fragment, I think the problem is cause I inflate view.

I try saveInstanceState, but I think the instance is never destroy and that's why when I run de code saveInstanceState is never called.

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_param, container, false);
    seekbarAffValeur();
    return myFragmentView;
}
```

this is my code when I change fragments.

```
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home_id:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new AcceuilFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Acceuil");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.setting_id:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new ParamFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Paramètres");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                    break;
                case R.id.about_id:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new ProposFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("À propos");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                case R.id.help_id:
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new AideFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Aide");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
            }
```

Thank you.

---

Ok, I found a solution, pretty easy finally.

```
private static int disPosiVal;
private static int disCarteVal;
private static int minPosiVal;
//Pour afficher la valeur des SeekBar.
public void seekbarAffValeur(){
    skbDisPosiValu = (SeekBar)   myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.skbDisPosi);
    tvDisPosi = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tvValeurDisPosi);
    skbDisCarteValu = (SeekBar)   myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.skbDisCarte);
    tvDisCarte = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tvValeurDisCarte);
    skbMinuValue = (SeekBar)   myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.skbMinPosi);
    tvMinuValu = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tvValeurMinPosio);

    skbDisPosiValu.setProgress(disPosiVal);
    tvDisPosi.setText(disPosiVal+ "");
    skbDisCarteValu.setProgress(disCarteVal);
    tvDisCarte.setText(disCarteVal+"");
    skbMinuValue.setProgress(minPosiVal);
    tvMinuValu.setText(minPosiVal+"");

    skbDisPosiValu.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            disPosiVal = progress;
            tvDisPosi.setText(progress + "");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            tvDisPosi.setText(disPosiVal + "");

        }

    });
    skbDisCarteValu.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            disCarteVal = progress;
            tvDisCarte.setText(progress + "");
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            tvDisCarte.setText(disCarteVal + "");
        }
    });
    skbMinuValue.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            minPosiVal = progress;
            tvMinuValu.setText(progress + "");
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            tvMinuValu.setText(minPosiVal + "");
        }
    });
```

The view is destroy but not the fragments (I think), so I just save my value in a static variable and when the view is created I set value where it belong.

Comment: Where are you setting the seekbar value? It would also be helpful if you posted the code where you change the displayed fragment.

Comment: The value is set when a user change the progress of the seekBar. I edit my answer to be more clear. I will add the code when I change my fragment later tonight, thanks.

Comment: Did you try my solution below?

Comment: No yet cause it work now when I store the values of my seekbar in a variable. The view is delete not the fragment, so the fragment keep the variable values and I just put it back when OnViewCreated is called.
But I will try it this week.

Comment: Finally I use this [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer). I try your solution but I was not able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the issue - `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new AcceuilFragment());`

You are basically removing the old fragment. What you need to do is

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new AcceuilFragment().addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

addToBackStack() basically puts fragments onto a stack. So u can call popBackStack() to fetch the fragment.`enter code here`

Documentation:

[FragmentManager popBackStack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html)

[FragmentTransaction addToBackStack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)